# make ``quote'' output as “quote„

Tags: punctuation

I have a document in which everything is quoted in the form:

```
``quote''
```

How do I make them appear in the output document as

> “quote„

thanks

Comment: You can't: `\csquotes` has its own commands and doesn't act on explicit quotes.

Comment: @Geremia -- If no one comes up with a better solution, you may try \def\lq{\raisebox{-6pt}{''}} and then use an editor to replace all right '' with \lq. Not fully automatic yet, this may point a direction to a solution.

Comment: @Jesse If you do something like that, you can drop some crazy `\raisebox` and use `\textquotedblbase`. Or skip `\lq` entirely and use `csquotes` package.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something that works for me.  It is based on making the right single quote an active character in TeX.  I must admit I have no confidence that this doesn't break something else, especially in the light of the negative comment by @egreg to the original question.

Let's start with an example that contains a number of quotations.  The first line shows how we would like double quotes to appear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This is the \textquotedblleft{}quote\quotedblbase{} that I'd want.

Let's play with some ``double quotes'' and
some ``more double quotes''            and yet ``some more''
and then with some `single quotes' and
some `more single quotes'          and yet `some more'
and see what happens.
\end{document}
```

[image: before]

Now, by adding the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`'=\active
\def'{\futurelet\@rqpeek\@rqhack}
\def\@rqhack{\ifx\@rqpeek'\expandafter\dbl@rq\else\rq\fi}
\def\dbl@rq'{\quotedblbase}
\makeatother
```

you can get what you want.

[image: after]

---

**EDIT:** After egreg's comment about this tweak breaking math that contains primes, like `$f'(x)$`, I'm providing a fix and concluding with a brief explanation and a disclaimer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=\active
\def'{\ifmmode\expandafter\active@math@prime\else\expandafter\@rqtext\fi}
\def\@rqtext{\futurelet\@rqpeek\@rqhack}
\def\@rqhack{\ifx\@rqpeek'\expandafter\dbl@rq\else\rq\fi}
\def\dbl@rq'{\quotedblbase}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the \textquotedblleft{}quote\quotedblbase{} that I'd want.

Let's play with some ``double quotes'' and
some ``more double quotes''            and yet ``some more''
and then with some `single quotes' and
some `more single quotes'          and yet `some more'
and see what happens.

Let's see some math too:
if $f(x) = x^2$ then $f'(x) = 2x$ and
$$f''(x) = 2$$

And some more `single' and ``double'' quotes.
\end{document}
```

[image: math too]

The fix comes in two parts.  First the active quote has to check whether it's found in math mode or text mode.  Second, the internal macro `\pr@m@s` (handling successive primes in math mode) has to be repeated here (verbatim from `latex.ltx`) because it checks whether the next character is `'` and now it has to check for an active `'`.

**Disclaimer:**
Making the single right quote an active character is expected to break everything that already treats it as an active character.  Examples that cross my mind are: the `babel` package (some languages with accents), various math packages like `euler`, various verbatim-text packages like the `alltt`.  But there are also packages, like `xspace` which (temporarily) set the `\catcode` of `\'` to 13.  I've tested `euler`, `alltt` and `xspace` and they seem to work fine with this.  All this said, you have been warned.  If a package breaks with this, I don't expect the fix to be obvious...

Comment: Of course this breaks math $f'(x)$, which is one of the drawbacks.

Comment: @egreg: If that's the only problem, I guess it can be fixed by making `'` non-active when in math mode.

Comment: @egreg: math was easy, I'm updating the answer.  I'll explain what else is expected to break and I'll stop here.